# Switching language from French to English in Solaris 8

Tags: solaris, sparc, language

I have Solaris 8 OS installed in French.

I have a computer with Solaris 8 OS and French language installed.
This computer isn't in my office; to access it I use Exceed.
I have to switch the installed language from `fr_FR.UTF-8` to `en_US.ISO8859-15`

How can I do that?

**P.S** :Even when i try to edit /etc/default/init and reboot : nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `en_GB` locale installed. Otherwise, you might want to switch to the `POSIX` locale (a.k.a. `C`).

Comment: i edited my question : it's `en_US` and when i use the command `locale -a` i have in my list `en_US.ISO8859-15`. I don't speak about `en_GB` but `en_US` i don't know why they edited my question ...

Comment: You wrote en_GB in your initial question, the various edits were adjusting the form, not the content.

Comment: Ok my bad then, have you an answer please ?

Comment: @jiligre it's not the same question : here i'm connecting to a computer from distance that's why i asked a new question

Comment: There is no evidence the problem you are describing here hasn't the same cause than the one in the other thread. First have the other issue fixed and ask for reopen should the solution doesn't apply here.